# Haskell - how to iterate list elements in reverse order in an elegant way?

Tags: list, haskell, iteration, reverse

I'm trying to write a function that given a list of numbers, returns a list where every 2nd number is doubled in value, starting from the last element. So if the list elements are 1..n, n-th is going to be left as-is, (n-1)-th is going to be doubled in value, (n-2)-th is going to be left as-is, etc.

So here's how I solved it:

```
MyFunc :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
MyFunc xs = reverse (MyFuncHelper (reverse xs))

MyFuncHelper :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
MyFuncHelper []       = []
MyFuncHelper (x:[])   = [x]
MyFuncHelper (x:y:zs) = [x,y*2] ++ MyFuncHelper zs
```

And it works:

```
MyFunc [1,1,1,1] = [2,1,2,1]
MyFunc [1,1,1] = [1,2,1]
```

However, I can't help but think there has to be a simpler solution than reversing the list, processing it and then reversing it again. Could I simply iterate the list backwards? If yes, how?

Comment: You can count elements and then double either every odd-numbered or every even-numbered element.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `under reversed f xs` idiom from the `lens` library will apply f to xs in reverse order:

```
under reversed (take 5) [1..100] => [96,97,98,99,100]
```

Comment: Note that `over reversed f xs` gives the same result here, and `over` is a much more commonly used lens combinator.

Comment: This definitely looks like the most concise way to solve the problem. It's a shame that the method used here isn't included in Prelude.

Comment: What is the time complexity of this operation? O(n)? or O(n^2)?

Answer (score 4):

When you need to process the list from the end, usually `foldr` works pretty well. Here is a solution for you without reversing the whole list twice:

```
doubleOdd :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
doubleOdd = fst . foldr multiplyCond ([], False)
    where multiplyCond x (rest, flag) = ((if flag then (x * 2) else x) : rest, not flag)
```

The `multiplyCond` function takes a tuple with a flag and the accumulator list. The flag constantly toggles on and off to track whether we should multiply the element or not. The accumulator list simply gathers the resulting numbers. This solution may be not so concise, but avoids extra work and doesn't use anything but prelude functions.

Comment: To produce the first element of the list in this function, the `fold` must recurse the whole way down to the end of the list and force the second (boolean) element of each of the pairs. So I'm skeptical that this is any better than reversing the original list.

Comment: @LuisCasillas Going to the end of the list is inevitable because the last item is inaccessible without looking at all the items before it. However, the resulting list is produced right away from the already retrieved elements, without the second reversing operation. Maybe with two reversals laziness achieves the same result, but I'm not entirely sure about that.

Answer (score 1):

```
myFunc = reverse
       . map (\(b,x) -> if b then x*2 else x)
       . zip (cycle [False,True])
       . reverse
```

But this isn't much better. Your implementation is sufficiently elegant.

Comment: You could code-golf this down to ``myFunc = reverse . zipWith (*) (cycle [1, 2]) . reverse``

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to iterate the list backwards is to reverse the list.  I don't think you can really do much better than that; I suspect that if you have to traverse the whole list to find the end, and remember how to get back up, you might as well just reverse it.  If this is a big deal, maybe you should be using some other data structure instead of lists—[`Vector`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.10.9.1/docs/Data-Vector.html) or [`Seq`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.3.1/docs/Data-Sequence.html) might be good choices.

Another way to write your helper function is to use `Traversable`:

```
import Control.Monad.State
import Data.Traversable (Traversable, traverse)

toggle :: (Bool -> a -> b) -> a -> State Bool b
toggle f a = 
    do active <- get
       put (not active)
       return (f active a)

doubleEvens :: (Num a, Traversable t) => t a -> t a
doubleEvens xs = evalState (traverse (toggle step) xs) False
    where step True x  = 2*x
          step False x = x

yourFunc :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
yourFunc = reverse . doubleEvens
```

---

Or if we go a bit crazy with `Foldable` and `Traversable`, we can try this:

1. Use `Foldable`'s `foldl` to extract a reverse-order list from any of its instances.  For some types this will be more efficient than reversing a list.
2. Then we can use `traverse` and `State` to map each element of the original structure to its counterpart in the reversed order.

Here's how to do it:

```
import Control.Monad.State
import Data.Foldable (Foldable)
import qualified Data.Foldable as F
import Data.Traversable (Traversable, traverse)
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map


toReversedList :: Foldable t => t a -> [a]
toReversedList = F.foldl (flip (:)) []

reverse' :: Traversable t => t a -> t a
reverse' ta = evalState (traverse step ta) (toReversedList ta)
    where step _ = do (h:t) <- get
                      put t
                      return h

yourFunc' :: (Traversable t, Num a) => t a -> t a
yourFunc' = reverse' . doubleEvens 

-- >>> yourFunc'  $ Map.fromList [(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1)]
-- fromList [(1,2),(2,1),(3,2),(4,1)]

-- >>> yourFunc' $ Map.fromList [(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1)]
-- fromList [(1,1),(2,2),(3,1)]
```

There's probably a better way to do this, though...

Answer (score 0):

`func xs = zipWith (*) xs $ reverse . (take $ length xs) $ cycle [1,2]`